# Apple Script to extract cropped eps images and save new images in a separate folder

Tags: image, applescript, export, adobe-indesign, eps

I am wondering if anyone has an AppleScript to extract cropped EPS files from an INDD CS5/CS6 document and save the cropped images into a new folder.

I have seen a lot of posts for CS3 and tried to adjust the AppleScript to work for me but cannot get the images to save.

I need them at 300 dpi, eps format, binary, JPG preview for MAC OS and saved in a new folder. I am familiar with AppleScript and would prefer help with that if possible

I am new to scripting which is why this is a little tougher for me. It is for a LARGE catalog I am working on with 1300 images I am hoping to automate so I don't have to crop by hand.

It would be a HUGE time saver and minimize human error I am sure. Any help would be greatly appreciate for myself and to share with my coworkers.

Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't AppleScript, but this has become an indispensable part of my catalog workflow: https://sites.google.com/a/lapay.biz/www/imagestransformto100%25. I use it to scale/rotate/skew/crop to match the layout, then sharpen and relink.  It's pretty flexible and it should accomplish what you're trying to do.